# Get number of frames in video file using ffprobe in C# code

Tags: c#, count, ffmpeg, frame, ffprobe

I can successfully read number of framres in test.mp4 using Ffprobe on command prompt with following command:

```
>ffprobe -i 'c://test.mp4' -show_frames | find /c 'pict_type'
```

But when I try to run 'ffprobe.exe' from C# code with following paramters:

```
string params = " -i 'c://test.mp4' -show_frames | find /c 'pict_type'";
```

It errors as follows:

```
ffprobe version N-59453-gd52882f Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 30 2013 22:07:23 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 59.100 / 52. 59.100
  libavcodec     55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavformat    55. 22.101 / 55. 22.101
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  0.103 /  4.  0.103
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Argument '|' provided as input filename, but ''c://test.mp4'' was already specified.
```

How to fix this for C#?

I know there is a workaround using `Ffmpeg` instead but that way is not clean enough.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because the C# console doesn't support pipes or find. I would consider writing the find instances of pict_type in your C# using the result of the ffprobe output.

> string params = " -i 'c://test.mp4' -show_frames";

Something like:

> output.Count(x => x == "pict_type");

Answer (score 0):

If you run the process with the args:

```
-v 1 -print_format json -show_format -show_streams -find_stream_info \"{filePath}\"
```

You can JsonDeserialise the stdout into a report class. Then everything is available.

Though frame count is metadata if the video wasn't encoded with that you're going to need to do a

```
-count_streams
```

aswell to get the actual value and that takes aaaaaages.